# How to make multiple rigid bodies behave as a single object

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation

I have multiple rigid bodies and I want some of them being glued together in initial state and behave as a single object. Is there a way to keep them glued together and break apart at a later stage of the simulation?

Comment: how should they "behave as a single object"? fall by gravity? roll down a slope? adding some more details will help to understand what you are trying to achieve...

Comment: @m.ardito All the objects have the same physics parameters, and when 2 of them should be connected they should have same physics behavior as a single mesh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **Rigid Body Constraint** and keyframe **Enable** checkbox or set it to be **Breakable** (they will disconnect after collision - use **Threshold** value to control how strong this collision should be).

[image: settings]

Without Constraint:

[image: without]

With Constraint:

[image: with]